# ReactJs: Best Practice of defining event handlers

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events, event-handling

I recently started using ReactJs and I want to know what is the best practice of defining event handlers in React. This is how I've been using react event handlers:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick()}> 
        Click Me To increase counter
      </button>
      <div>
        <h4>Counter value is: </h4>
        {counter}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have also heard arguments against this logic. Some say it is better to define event handlers outside the definition of the component (`App` in our case). This way, it becomes clear, clean and concise, instead of creating a mess of multiple functions (event handlers or not) inside the component. For example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const handleButtonClick = (setCounter, counter) => () => {
  setCounter(counter+1);
};

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick(setCounter, counter)}> 
        Click Me To increase counter
      </button>
      <div>
        <h4>Counter value is: </h4>
        {counter}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link for second approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-rain-wzfv4)
I want to know which is the best practice of defining functions? Should event handlers be also defined globally above the function component(`App Component in this case`)?

Comment: Second one is also wrong implemented. It will go in infinite loop. My take on is like this if component has one or two function then inline is fine but if its more then its always to create a function above render/return as it will not create function copy. For `functional` component use `useCallback`

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, doesn't seem to go in infinite loop. Edited and pasted the codesandbox link for the same.
Also, in either case, functions are created above the render/return only. Just want to know whether to define it above the component definition or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should event handlers be also defined globally above the function component?

NO.

Defining event handlers, outside the component, that **modifies a component's state** breaks [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20cohesion%20refers,concept%20served%20by%20that%20class.).

An event handler, within a component, explains the different interactions of the component. Having a "wrapper" handler simply breaks the [single level of abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction).

My two cents.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an extra function inside onClick. Just don't call it. onClick method call when onClick trigger.

```js
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  setCounter(counter + 1);
};  // return function

<div onClick={handleButtonClick} />
// it will be call the handleButtonClick
// when onClick is trigger
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}> 
        Click Me To increase counter
      </button>
      <div>
        <h4>Counter value is: </h4>
        {counter}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```